# ActiveMQ MessageGroupHashBucket - what is cache property needed for?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to find a best strategy to deal with ActiveMQ Message Groups support.
ActiveMQ has several strategies (MessageGroupMap implementations).

The one that is confusing me a little is [MessageGroupHashBucket](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-broker/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/broker/region/group/MessageGroupHashBucket.java).
Specifically, after looking at sources, I don't understand why is the **cache** property needed there? When assigning consumer id for message group or retrieving consumer id by message group - the array of buckets is used.

It would be great if someone can suggest why.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MessageGroupHashBucket implements **MessageGroupMap interface method getGroups()** by returning the **cache** property as a map of all group names and associated consumer Id.

Comment: Thank you. Still looks it's really inconsistent implementation cause cache size doesn't correspond to buckets count and while one can't find a concrete group in a map returned by the getGroups() method - the get(String groupId) method would still return an assigned consumer. That's my primary confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @piola's answer, it looks like the **cache** property is used to configure the number of group names that will be inside a bucket. This is a very efficient way to handle a large number of groups. Going by this logic, a configuration of 1024 buckets with the cache size of 64 can handle 65,536 groups.